# What are the non-custom attributes for properties, functions, etc?

Tags: vb.net, attributes, default

I've been looking around the web and found lots of info on VB.NET attributes in general and creating and using *custom* attributes, as well as about 10 or so generic, non-custom attributes listed on MSDN.

However I have not been able to find info/ listing on the non-custom attributes available for use with certain things. Like for a property I can have `<EditorBrowsable(EditorBrowsableState.Always), Description("My properties description")>`

How can I find out what non-custom attributes are already available for use with what things (such as Functions, Properties, Classes, etc)?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Perhaps, "non-custom" is the wrong term.  I think what you are asking for is the list of attributes which are included as part of the .NET Framework.  That list, of course, will depend on what version of the framework you are targeting and which specific framework libraries you choose to reference in your project, but the MSDN provides a pretty comprehensive list of them [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.attribute.aspx#inheritanceContinued).

As far as determining which attributes can be applied to which types of elements (e.g. class, property, method, assembly), if you click on any of the links to view the MSDN page for any of the attribute classes, you'll notice in the **Syntax** section of the page it shows the declaration of the class.  Above the class declaration, you will see an `AttributeUsage` attribute applied to the attribute class.  *That's right--attributes can, themselves, have attributes too--stick with me.*

The first argument to the `AttributeUsage` attribute is called `ValidOn`.  It is a [`AttributeTargets`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.attributetargets.aspx) enumeration which defines the types of elements to which the attribute can be applied.  For instance, if the `AttributeUsage` attribute on the attribute class looks like `<AttributeUsage(AttributeTargets.All)>`, that means it can be applied to anything.  If however it looks like `<AttributeUsage(AttributeTargets.Class)>`, that means it can only be applied to a class.

Comment: Thanks Steven. Im using v4, mostly with ComponentModel. I note that a lot of these specify "for a property or event" does that mean they defo shouldn't be used with methods? In fact I cannot see any description attribute (for e.g.) for methods - do methods just go un-described? Cheers

Comment: I updated my answer to explain how to tell what attributes can be applied to what.  As far as the Description attribute goes, that is used to specifying the short descriptive help text that is displayed in the designer.  Since methods cannot be displayed or manipulated in the designer, it doesn't make sense to apply that attribute to a method.  If you want to add a description to a method that will show in the intellisense, you need to use XML comments.  To add XML comments, go to the blank line above your method and type `'''` (three apostrophes).